# Sending e-mail from a local host

Tags: php, email, mamp, local, host

I am trying to send an email from localhost, and the program I am using is MAMP. I have looked this up online and done everything written, but this still won't work. The function I have entered in my PHP file to send emails is:

```
mail(
     $admin_email, $messaage,
     'Works!',


    'An email has been generated from your localhost, congratulations!');
```

furthermore, I have filled out all the send mail value as shown below:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=25
smtp_ssl=ssl
auth_username=****@gmail.com
auth_password=*******

hostname=localhost
```

Obviously - my email and password are filled out using my email and password. Also I have altered the php.ini file as shown:

```
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
;http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = C:\Windows\System32\sendmail\ -t -i -f   my_email@gmail.com
```

Can someone tell me where my error is?

Comment: If you are running this from a home network, your ISP is likely blocking outbound traffic destined to port 25 as an anti-spam measure. Simply change your **smtp_port=25** to the alternate SMTP port 587 which usually isn't blocked: **smtp_port=587**

Comment: i tried this... still not working :(

Comment: Try commenting out the ssl as well

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to be able to send via Google's SMTP server because the `mail()` function doesn't perform [SSL or TLS authentication, which is required](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619150/how-to-send-emails-using-google-smtp-server-using-xampp) for more information. You should consider using the [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) class instead.

Also, please note that you're using [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) incorrectly. You have

```
mail(
 $admin_email, $messaage,
 'Works!',
'An email has been generated from your localhost, congratulations!');
```

The second argument should be a subject, and the third should be the message. The fourth argument is optional and is supposed to contain extra mail headers:

> **additional_headers** (optional)
>
> String to be inserted at the end of the email header.
>
> This is typically used to add extra headers (From, Cc, and Bcc). Multiple extra headers should be separated with a CRLF (`\r\n`). If outside data are used to compose this header, the data should be sanitized so that no unwanted headers could be injected.

It is not for a plaintext message like you are using. By adding plaintext where a properly-formatted header should be, you are likely to break some servers and some mail readers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `smtp_port=25`you have to change `smtp_ssl=none` or use this

```
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=tls
```

Have you changed these settings from your gmail account

> Access your email account. Click the Gear Tool > Settings > Forwarding
>   and POP/IMAP > IMAP access. Click "Enable IMAP", then save your
>   changes
>
> For check email use these code

```html
<?php
$to      = 'myemail@yahoo.com';
$subject = 'Fake sendmail test';
$message = 'If we can read this, it means that our fake Sendmail setup works!';
$headers = 'From: myemail@egmail.com' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: myemail@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo 'Email sent successfully!';
} else {
    die('Failure: Email was not sent!');
}
?>
```

Comment: Check your Sendmail path I using like that **sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"**